# Difference of instantiate an object with new <object>(){ } and new<object>{ } in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I am somewhat confused when instantiate class in C#.
Here is what I usually do

In Model :

```
public class ModelView
{
    public string inputfield1 { get; set; }
    public string inputfield2 { get; set; }
    public List<DataGrid1> Grids { get; set; }

}

public class DataGrid1
{
    public string row1 { get; set; }
    public string row2 { get; set; }
    public string row3 { get; set; }
}
```

And in controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ModelView result = new ModelView //this is where I confused
    {
        inputfield1 = " ",
        inputfield2 = " ",
        Grids = new List<DataGrid1>()
    };
    return View(result);
}
```

In a lot of example I see people do this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ModelView result = new ModelView()
    {
        inputfield1 = " ",
        inputfield2 = " ",
        Grids = new List<DataGrid1>()
    };
    return View(result);
}
```

I did try this and it works too. My question is

What's the difference between using **()** and not when instantiate a class?

Comment: no difference here:`()` stands for using default constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining object with inline properties, `()` brackets are optional. That's why this works

```
ModelView result = new ModelView()
{
    inputfield1 = " "
};
```

and this too

```
ModelView result = new ModelView
{
    inputfield1 = " "
};
```

but when properties are not defined inline, brackets are compulsory.

```
ModelView result = new ModelView();
result.inputfield1 = " ";
```

This won't work

```
 ModelView result = new ModelView;
```